# Which saddle is suitable for me?

Tags: saddle, gel-saddle

I have a question about saddles. I bought a mountain bike 2 days ago. I thought it would be better to ride a bike rather than going on a walk in these Corona days (for exercise purpose). My bike is MOSSO Raceline 29" alloy frame. My weight is 138kg and my height is 1,95 cm. Bike shop guy recommended me this bike because I am overweight. When I ride the bike, the saddle gives me a lot of pain to my butt. I read forums, they say you'll get used to it in 2 weeks but I am not sure because of excess weight. I checked on the internet that there are some gel saddles (Selle Royal). But I am not sure which one will be comfortable and suitable for me. Please consider that I only ride on the bicycle on the road (not going mountain or unbalanced terrains), I use it like a road bike. If anyone has any saddle purchase experience can you please share it with me? Thanks for your help guys.

[image: Mosso bike image]

Comment: Buy a gel padded seat cover to fit your saddle.  If you Google it you will find many options.  Just be sure what you get is close to your saddle dimensions.  (Oh, and shave your butt.  You don't have to give it a razor shave, just trim with electric beard trimmer or some such to remove the long hairs, especially those close to the "crack".  These get tangled and cause a lot of pain, and having them pull out "naturally" is a big part in "breaking in" your butt.)

Comment: I can't find specs for the standard saddle on that bike, or a clear picture of it, but what I see suggests it's not *real* narrow, but is probably narrower than you should be riding.  So you should probably buy a new, wider saddle at a bike shop, or, if necessary, online.  The existing saddle appears to use the standard two-rail mounting scheme, so swapping in a different saddle should be relatively straight-forward.

Comment: If you just bought the bike, go back to the bike shop and discuss with them. A side benefit is the after sales service they give you now will provide a useful guide as to what kind of shop they are) Often they will replace a saddle with another that's a different shape (e.g. wider to better fit your sit bones).

Comment: I recommend you examine some diagrams that show what a bike saddle does to our butt, and where the sit bones are, and how they push through the body tissues and contact the saddle. You will see that big squishy saddles make the problem worse because the softness of the saddle actually squishes up into your tissue and can make pain worse. This is not to say that you should not use a soft saddle, just that sitting on a bike saddle does hurt, and you will get used to it. Riding a bike is about legs, heart, and lungs, but also about butts, hands, and necks. You will get better at it all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cause is that you've mistaken the saddle for a seat.  The main difference is that a saddle does not hold all your weight - some amount of your weight sits on the pedals and a small amount on the hands.

By comparison, a seat holds 100% of your weight, and you could ride with no weight on the feet or hands.  This wouldn't work.

Other items that have saddles include horses and motorbikes (which have stirrups and footpegs respectively)  whereas seats are at the dining-room table, in cars, and recumbents.

**Suggestion**  try transferring some of your weight through the pedals rather than putting all your weight on the saddle.  The downside of this is that its more pressure through your knees, which can cause aches.

---

Separately, the material of your saddle is a completely personal choice.  Some people are perfectly happy with hard plastic or carbon saddle. Some people find a squishy padded saddle works best for them.

A Gel or heavily padded saddle will squish out from under your sit-bones (ischial tuberosity  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ischial_tuberosity ) and will put pressure on the softer tissues.  In more-extreme cases the padding will put pressure on your soft tissues, flesh  that shouldn't be bearing any weight.  This is one of the causes of penile numbness in males and similar in female cyclists.

Just to be clear, your butt doesn't support your weight.  Your sit-bones, part of your skeleton hold basically all your weight.

Another thought is perhaps your existing saddle is the wrong width for your sit-bones.  On a too-narrow saddle your sit bones will hang off the side, causing weight to be held on the soft flesh.  If your saddle is too wide, its not quite as bad.  There are a couple of existing questions with answers on this topic already:

- [Is it possible to measure your sit bones at home?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9815/is-it-possible-to-measure-your-sit-bones-at-home)
- [What type of saddle doesn't hurt the pelvic bone?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9510/what-type-of-saddle-doesnt-hurt-the-pelvic-bone/)

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. I am very new to riding a bike. Recently I figured out that there are many modifications you can make on the bike to get yourself more comfortable. I am overweight and I am worried about the problems may occur in the future if I keep going with default saddle. I just wonder if replacing the saddle will make it healthier to ride a bike.

Comment: Getting a saddle that was not too narrow made a _huge_ difference for me.  I would definitely recommend doing a fit-check on your saddle.

Comment: @AhmetAtakan yep - its possible to change many things, but that can be both expensive and often minimal improvement if any.  The three basic contact points (bum, hands, feet) are worth considering.  Remember changes don't have to be expensive.   Read the linked questions, something will reference how to measure your sitbones at home, either with corrugated cardboard or similar.

Comment: @DavidW - Yep, a saddle that is too narrow is not a good idea for a heavy guy, especially if he has a wide pelvis.

Comment: @AhmetAtakan to clarify - the width of your pelvis and therefore sit bones is nothing to do with weight, and once a person is fully grown that width is fixed and unchangable.  Females tend to be slightly wider hips than males, but there's no practical difference other than the width required of your bike saddle.

Comment: It may also be a better idea to get padded cycling shorts and a good chamois cream.

Comment: @Carel excellent point - you should totally make that an answer too.

Comment: @Criggie: but (no wordplay here) it is more opinion based than backed by evidence, though it's a general opinion among cyclists. That's why I would not make an answer from that!

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I was searching for suitable saddle for a month. I decided to buy Sell Royal Respiro Moderate. It is much more comfortable than the default one and it has ventilation space in the middle of the saddle( I sweat a lot in summer). Anyone used this saddle before?

Comment: @AhmetAtakan this is not a chat forum - comments are for clarifying and improving the answer/question.  Consider [chat] instead.